# How to give attribution for Open Source Licenses used in commercial SaaS web-applications?

Tags: licensing, commercial, attribution

Say I commercialize a SaaS Web Application that uses a component licensed under [GNU GPL v3](https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-general-public-license-v3-(gpl-3)) (like [CKEditor5](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/)) or under [Apache 2.0 license](https://tldrlegal.com/license/apache-license-2.0-(apache-2.0)) (like [Material Design Icons](https://materialdesignicons.com/)), where and how should I give attribution for those components?

They are never distributed as source code, though they are running in the browser as bundled, minified JavaScript.

The Angular build process generates a file named `3rdpartylicenses.txt` listing all components and all licenses. It's deployed on the web server.

Is that sufficient or should there be a "3rd party components" section in the SaaS' "Terms of Service"? If so, what should be listed? Is a simple link to the `3rdpartylicenses.txt` mentioned above sufficient?

Comment: If your server provides (minified) JS to the user's browser, you most  certainly *are* distributing it.  Have you read [this question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9258/how-does-javascript-minification-process-comply-with-requirements-of-opensource), and does it help any?

Comment: @MadHatter, I'm not sure. Unless you are saving that "as long as I do not strip out the JS comments indicating the license of those components from the bundled JavaScript, I do not need to write anything else anywhere", then that is not really my question.

Comment: Is your question "*I am distributing GPLv3 and Apache2-licensed javascript, what do I need to do to be license-compliant*"?  Because it seems to me that's what you're asking, even though it's not what you've written.

Comment: Sort of, yes. I clarified the question.

Comment: If that's what you want to ask, I **strongly** recommend that you ask it.  Questions that say "*I want to do this with this piece of software, is this my obligation?*" can simply be answered "*no*", and are thus not as useful to the greater community, nor as edifying for the asker, as questions that ask "*I want do do this with this piece of software, what are my obligations?*".

Comment: I did write "where and how should I give attribution for those components?"... ;)

Comment: Yes, you did,  But attribution won't be the sum total of your obligations, especially in the case of the GPL component.  And the answer to your closing question is simply "*no*", in every non-trivial case I can think of.  Do you see the problem?