# How should I put attribution or license when using a minified version of code which does not assert copyright?

Tags: licensing, bsd

I am using some JavaScript code under the BSD 3-Clause License. However, the minified version that they provided does not assert the said license.
Is it fine if I just copy the license provided in their repository and place it in the same directory of their code?

Comment: Have you read [our question on JS minification](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/9258/how-does-javascript-minification-process-comply-with-requirements-of-opensource)?  If not, could you do so, then clarify if there's anything you still need to know?