# Am I legally obligated to disclose that my web app is using AngularJS?

Tags: licensing, license-recommendation, license-notice

I am using AngularJS in a web app I am building, and I'm wondering about the legal obligation of disclosing that my app uses AngularJS, and whether I need to make AngularJS's licence agreement available on my website. My reasoning is: if my users are using AngularJS through my app, they are subject to the terms of AngularJS's licence, and therefore must be informed of this fact.
Is this the case legally?

Comment: AngularJS is MIT licensed. See: [Where to put license for MIT licensed code on website](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/where-to-put-license-for-mit-licensed-code-on-website)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to put license for MIT licensed code on website](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/where-to-put-license-for-mit-licensed-code-on-website)

Comment: Receivers of open source software aren't bound by its license, only people who go on to distribute it to others.