# Where should I include the license and copyright notice into my website?

Tags: license-notice

My website used TailwindCSS, and other OSS.

1. TailwindCSS (generated the css) (imported via npm install)
2. typed.js (imported via `<script src=""></script>` from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/2.0.12/typed.min.js)

Surely, I must include the license and copyright notice `The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.`

Will one page for listing OSS (and the license) used in my website be enough? Like at https://discord.com/licenses .

Do I need to add the (used) library's dependencies too? If yes, is there any tools that can automatically generate the license page?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where to put license for MIT licensed code on website](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/where-to-put-license-for-mit-licensed-code-on-website)

Answer (score 4):

Both Tailwind CSS and TypedJS appear to be licensed under the [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT). It is good practice to have the license and copyright attribution on one page of your website (usually somewhere close to the 'About' page).

Both CSS and JS code is actually delivered to the browser, so this qualifies as distributing a copy according to the terms of the MIT license. Therefore you are actually required to provide the license and copyright information to the visitors of your site.

And yes, you should also include the information for the direct and transitive dependencies. They will likely also have a permissive license compatible with MIT. If it is just a handful of dependencies it is likely the easiest to do that manually. If it is a large number you  might want to use a specialized tool such as [FOSSology](https://www.fossology.org/) or the like.

Comment: Does one have to include a license for Tailwind CSS given that you bundle output from Tailwind CSS and not the Tailwind CSS itself?

Comment: The code of Tailwind CSS (at least parts of it) is delivered to the client browser, therefore I think that your assumption is wrong. There is no 'output' that is completely separate from Tailwind CSS.