# According to this web site unless I am sharing or selling my website code I dont have to attribute anything about the mit license, is that truth?

Tags: mit, license-recommendation

This is the answers I am refering to:
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/how-to-put-the-themes-mit-license-information-on-my-website/32001.

Edit: They talk about a difference between serving in a web page and sharing or selling a code. Remember a MIT license is a software license, so even if they are talking about themes they are talking about the code and software behind. So my question is if am just serving as the answers explain,Do I still have to attribute in a MIT license?.

Comment: The website you are referring to talks about themes, your question talks about "website code". This is obviously a different scope. My recommendation is that you just read the [MIT License](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) and then specifically ask what remains unclear to you.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Martin_in_AUT although then at that point the question just reduces to the [poster's question on Friday which also needs clarification](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/13219/i-add-a-third-party-license-text-next-to-me-index-file-of-my-react-app-build-is).

Comment: I already edit the question, is clear enough?

Comment: See also this related question with good answers: [Where to put license for MIT licensed code on website](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6342/where-to-put-license-for-mit-licensed-code-on-website)

Answer (score 1):

(Apart from the webserver itself and server side scripts,) HTML, XML, JS, CSS or whatever else your website sends to the browser to display the content is code, and you are distributing that code from the server to the client.

Therefore there is no difference between 'serving a webpage' and 'sharing code'. It is the same. You must therefore respect the requirements of the MIT license for the 3rd party components of your website.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification that was the point.  So the code in my backend also needs give proper attribution in a MIT license?

Comment: If the code in your backend is sent to the browser, then yes. But usually 'backend' means that it is not sent to the browser.